# Change DataGridView Binding from on Validation to on Change

Tags: data-binding, datagridview

How do I programmatically change the binding for a datagridview in C# so that the binding happens when the user changes the value in a cell rather than when the validation occurs which is not until after he/she tabs out of the cell?

Comment: It is difficult to understand exactly when you want the binding to change. If the `CellValidating` is wired up properly, it will fire when the user presses the “enter/tab” key or clicks on another control/cell. What would the user “type” that would trigger this “binding change” BEFORE the user clicks away or presses the enter key?

Comment: The cell in question has a checkbox in it, and I want the binding to be triggered when the user clicks on the check box and changes it from checked to unchecked, or vice versa.

Comment: This sounds like an odd requirement, I mean “changing” the grids binding source by clicking one of the check boxes “IN” the grid itself does not sound very user friendly. I would think having the check box “external” of the grid would be more appropriate.

Comment: However, I am guessing that one approach would be to wire up the `DataGridView.CellContentClick` event. When fired, check to see if the cell whose content was clicked is the check box column and if so, check if the check box is “checked” or “un-checked” and change the binding accordingly. Again, I can only imagine what the user is going to make of this behavior.

Comment: @JohnG, the underlying data source is a custom `SortedBindingList<MyCustomType>` collection of objects of a custom type, and the type of the properties the checkboxes are bound to are Booleans. How else would you bind them? There are other displayed properties in the grid that are affected by the Boolean value of these properties that should (need?) to be updated when the user checks on the cell and changes the checked/unchecked value of the check boxes.

Comment: Ok, so you need to do this in the grid. I am guessing there may be something else going on, however, have you tried my previous suggestion? I have tested wiring up the `CellContentClick` event and it should work for what you want to do. If you did try this, did it work as expected, did it crash… what happen?